# How can I check for close notify from the server before sending the request

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL 3.0.9. I'm trying to write C++ code that does this:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -tls1_2 -no_ticket -CAfile <file>
```

When the server timeout ends, it sends a "close notify" notification and the application closes responding.

However, in my code, the only way to get the message is `BIO_read()`, which initializes the SSL connection state. And then use `if (SSL_get_shutdown(ssl) == SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN)`. If bio is blocking, then `BIO_read` will cause the application to hang on the server timeout. And I can't `BIO_read()` before `BIO_write()`.

How can I find out about the connection status before sending the request?

How can I initialize the connection status?

Is it possible to do this with blocking bio?

My code:

```cpp
string receive_some_data(BIO* bio)
{
    SSL* ssl;
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);

    char buffer[1024];
    int len = BIO_read(bio, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (len < 0) {
        reportAndExit("Error in reading response");
    }
    else if (len > 0) {
        return std::string(buffer, len);
    }
    else if (BIO_should_retry(bio)) {
        return receive_some_data(bio);
    }
    else if (len == 0 && (SSL_get_shutdown(ssl) == SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN) ) {
        reportAndExit("Get 'close notify' from server");
    }
    else {
        reportAndExit("Empty response");
    }
}
```

```cpp
...

SSL_CTX* ctx;
BIO* tmpBio = nullptr;
SSL* tmpSsl = nullptr;

auto method_ = TLS_client_method();

if (NULL == method_) reportAndExit("Error initializations of the client method");
                    
tmpBio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx_);

if (NULL == tmpBio) reportAndExit("Error creating a new TLS connection");

BIO_get_ssl(tmpBio, &tmpSsl);

if (tmpSsl == NULL) {
   reportAndExit("Get session error");
}

SSL_set_mode(tmpSsl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY); 

setBioConnectParam(tmpBio, host, port);

if (BIO_do_handshake(tmpBio) <= 0) {
   reportAndExit("Handshake error");
}

while (true) {
    auto connectionStatus = SSL_get_shutdown(tmpSsl);

    string msg = "Reset connect, because ";

    if (connectionStatus == SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN) {
        msg += "SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN";
        }
    if (connectionStatus == SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN) {
        msg += "SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN";
    }

    if (connectionStatus > 0) {
        // reconnect after shutdown
        BIO_reset(tmpBio);
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << msg;
    }

    std::string request = "GET " + pageName + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    request += "Host: " + domen + "\r\n";
    
    request += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
    
    request += "\r\n";

    int n = BIO_write(tmpBio, request.data(), request.size());
    BIO_flush(tmpBio);

    std::string headers = receive_some_data(tmpBio);
    char* end_of_headers = strstr(&headers[0], "\r\n\r\n");

    while (end_of_headers == nullptr) {
        headers += receive_some_data(tmpBio);
        end_of_headers = strstr(&headers[0], "\r\n\r\n");
    }

    std::string body = std::string(end_of_headers + 4, &headers[headers.size()]);
    headers.resize(end_of_headers + 2 - &headers[0]);
    size_t content_length = 0;

    for (const std::string& line : splitHeaders(headers)) {
        if (const char* colon = strchr(line.c_str(), ':')) {
            auto header_name = std::string(&line[0], colon);
            if (header_name == "Content-Length") {
                content_length = std::stoul(colon + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    while (body.size() < content_length) {
        body += receive_some_data(bio_);
    }

    std::string result = headers + "\r\n" + body;
    
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(7s);
}
```

I looked at how the browser works when receiving a message about closing the connection:
[captured for browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm4J5.png)

But but my program:
[captured for my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDUNt.png)

My program send a request after close notify, but shouldn't do this.

Comment: Per the `BIO_read` documentation: "*if a call to BIO_read() on a socket BIO returns 0 and BIO_should_retry() is false then the cause will be that the connection closed*". So you don't need `SSL_get_shutdown()`. If the connection is closed, `BIO_read()` will stop blocking and report failure. Also, your check for `len == 0` is redundant since you already handled the `< 0` and `> 0` cases beforehand, so `len` *must* be 0 at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The server sends a message about the termination of the connection between the client's reading and writing. When the client reads data from BIO, the connection is not interrupted. But when the client writes data, the server has already sent a "close notification" message. And I want to check it before sending.

Comment: Doing that check beforehand introduces a [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use). At the time you check, the connection may not have been closed yet, but by the time you do send it might have been closed. There is no point in checking for close before sending. You should just send normally and let it fail if the connection has been closed, and then handle the failure as needed. If the send doesn't fail (because sent data is buffered, etc), then reading the response will alert you to the closure.

Comment: I checked how the browser works in this situation. I added the result to the question. The browser resumes the connection after receiving the "close notify".  How do I implement the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything better than using `select()` before writing the data.

```
bool checkCloseNotify(BIO* bio)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    int len = BIO_read(bio, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    if (len < 0) {
        reportAndThrow("Error in checking close notify response");
    }
    else if (len > 0) {
        reportAndThrow("Error in checking  close notify response. Data is received!");
    }
    else if (len == 0) { 
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}

FD_ZERO(&readfds); 
FD_SET(SSL_get_fd(tmpSsl), &readfds);

if (-1 == (resultSelect = select(0, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &time_out))) {
                reportAndThrow("Error!");
}

if ((resultSelect != 0) && (FD_ISSET(SSL_get_fd(tmpSsl), &readfds))) {
                // reconnect after shutdown
                if (checkCloseNotify(tmpBio)) {
                    SSL_set_shutdown(tmpSsl, 1);

                    BIO_reset(tmpBio);
                }
}
```